# Appinstaller issue with side loaded UWP application

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, appinstaller

I have an UWP application which has been used now for quite some time without any issue on all sort of devices.
The `.appinstaller` and packaging is side loaded and hosted on a blob storage in azure, and signed with a valid certificate.

But since yesterday on some devices (it seems to be laptops, not tablets) I have the following error message in the windows appinstaller which checks if updates are available:

`Cannot open app package`
`Failed due to unknown reason.`

When I look into the event viewer here is the detailed error message I get:

`Appinstaller operation failed with error code 0x80670001. Detail: Optimistic locking failure. Data cannot be updated if it has changed since it was read.`

I've checked and those devices have the minimal OS version required for the app.

What is happening is the following: I can install the app on the faulty device, which then run the app without any issue.
But whenever I close and try to open the app again, I get this error message.

Rebooting the machine doesn't change anything, and the same behavior occurs whenever I uninstall and reinstall the app (working then displaying the error on re-launch).

I've even tried to revert to an older release of the UWP app, and the problem also happens while it never occured before.

The overall issue seems to have started to appear yesterday, without any changes in our release.

Has anybody encountered this message error and have an idea about how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am facing the same issue. The only workaround is to start the .appinstaller every time and select 'Launch' instead of 'Reinstall'. Starting from the 'Start Menu' or 'Taskbar' does not work, as described.

Comment: This indeed works. I'll have to check if this still allows for updates or not when started that way

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue starting at the exact same time but it seems to have sorted itself out now.

--- Wonder if UWP apps needed to go off to some Microsoft server each time they were booted for some reason and there was a server issue.

Comment: I still have the issue, but the response above gives a workaround which keeps the application usable

Comment: Glad the workaround helps you. On my end I've check for windows updates to see if anything could have affected the app but there were no updates between the issue starting and stopping for me.

Comment: It seems to affect devices randomly. One of my test device has the exact same OS version / build than another: one is working fine the other has the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).